# Service are stopped in MI devices When press clear memory button from recent

Tags: android, service

I want to running my service 24x7 continuesly I achieve this all most but some device service are stopped. when we click on recent button and click on clear memory in MI device at that time it will killed my service. I try lots of but not able to solve this problem.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 2):

Did you make your service sticky?
try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml file and check.

Comment: @Sahdev, please explain the issue so that we can understand it well and can help you with this. I was also stuck in something like this.

Comment: i already try all but MI device kill service when clear memory from recent